# How to change logic inside for loop to match an element of an array?

Tags: jquery

I have 50 elements in a javascript array .

For  20  elements in the above javascript array ,  i need to do some manipulation while displaying them within for loop(adding class style dynamically)

This is my code

```
var stocks=['ABAN','ADANIENT','ADVANTA']; // i have 50 elemnts in array 

for(var i=0;i<stocks.length;i++)
{
   var stockname = stocks[i];

    if(stockname=='ABAN' || stockname=='ADANIENT')  // do i  need to write 20 elements inside the for loop 
    {
     console.log('print');   
    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k34dbefs/1/

Comment: If you are matching individual names, then yes. It might be cleaner to have an array of those twenty names and then just `$.inArray()` or something to check in the if statement.

Comment: Do you have some identifier other than just a name? A type or anything?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<stocks.length;i++)
{
   var stockname = stocks[i];

    if(jQuery.inArray(stockname, stocks) > -1)
    {
     console.log('print');   
    }   
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/k34dbefs/9/**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it this way.

```
var stocks=[
        {name:'ABAN',check:'1'},
        {name:'ADANIENT',check:'1'},
        {name:'ADVANTA',check:'0'}
        ]; 

for(var i=0;i<stocks.length;i++)
{
  var check = stocks[i].check;

   if(check=='1')
   {
      alert(stocks[i].name);
   }
   else
   {

   }  
}
```

put 1 for the check value of the first 20 names .

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
   var stocks2 = stocks[i];

    if ($.inArray(stocks2, stocks) > -1) {
     console.log('print');   
    }   
}
```